# Can't use my "type" ComplexNumber without "new"--why?

Tags: java, new-operator

[The Mandelbrot set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMandel_zoom_00_mandelbrot_set.jpg) has been a favorite of mine for many years. I've successfully created it in Pascal years ago and more recently on a TI-83 graphing calculator (Java renders it juuuuust a bit faster).

Since complex numbers are involved, I took a version from a text that `extends RecursiveAction` using a `BufferedImage` and `ForkJoinPool` (without understanding the those concepts and the overall implementation) and, using routines I developed a few months ago, modified (the heck out of) the code that does the point-plotting so that it looks more like complex numbers are involved.

Original:

```
public class MandelbrotTask extends RecursiveAction  {
```

...

```
public void render() {
```

...

```
for (int x = xStart; x <= xEnd; x++) {
  for (int y = yStart; y <= yEnd; y++) {
    double r = x * zoomFactor / image.getWidth() - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetX;
    double i = y * zoomFactor / image.getHeight() - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetY;
    double zr = 0, zi = 0;
    int iter;
    for (iter = 0; iter < maxIter; iter++) {
      double nzr = zr * zr - zi * zi + r;
      double nzi = 2 * zr * zi + i;
      if (nzr * nzr + nzi * nzi > escapeRadius * escapeRadius)
        break;
      zr = nzr;
      zi = nzi;
    }
    image.setRGB(x, y, Color.HSBtoRGB(0.5f * iter / maxIter, 1.0f, 1.0f));
  }
}
```

My revised, somewhat-cleaner code:

```
for (int x = xStart; x <= xEnd; x++) {
  for (int y = yStart; y <= yEnd; y++) {
    z1 = new ComplexNumber(x * dx - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetX,
                           y * dy - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetY);
    z0 = new ComplexNumber(0,0);
    int iter;
    for (iter = 0; iter < maxIter; iter++) {
      nz = cAdd(cMult(z0,z0),z1);
      if (cAbs(nz) > escapeRadius )
        break;
      z0 = nz;
    }
    image.setRGB(x, y, Color.HSBtoRGB(0.5f * iter / maxIter, 1.0f, 1.0f));
  }
}
```

My only question is **how to get rid of "new" on the two lines defining z1 and z0**. It seems like I'm wasting a ton of memory since the two objects get "newed" a total of 1,000,000+ times during the almost 25,000 executions of the above block of code, though there's no problem as is.

I know I need `new` at least once inside the method, but if I put the statements (shown below) outside the loop (and either inside or outside `render()`), if I omit `new` from those two lines defining z1 and z0 in the block of code above, I get the error 
"cannot find symbol: method ComplexNumber(double,double) location: class MandelbrotTask."

```
z1 = new ComplexNumber();
z0 = new ComplexNumber();
```

---- edit 10:21 12/26/13

Here is the part of the ComplexNumber class that is invovled. The constructor call `ComplexNumber()` sets `real` and `imag`-inary parts to 0.

```
class ComplexNumber {
  public double real;       
  public double imag;       

  public ComplexNumber() {
    real = 0.0;
    imag = 0.0;
  }

  public ComplexNumber(double r, double i) {
    this.real = r;
    this.imag = i;
  }

    public static ComplexNumber cAdd(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
    return new ComplexNumber(a.real + b.real, a.imag + b.imag);
  }

  public static ComplexNumber cMult(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
   return new ComplexNumber(a.real * b.real - a.imag * b.imag, a.real * b.imag + a.imag * b.real);
  }

  public static double sqr(double x) {
    return x * x;
  }

  public static double cAbs(ComplexNumber z) {
    return Math.sqrt(sqr(z.real) + sqr(z.imag));
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you add methods to the class `ComplexNumber` to set the real and imaginary parts? E.g. `z1.setImaginary(0); z1.setReal(0);` instead of `z1 = new ComplexNumber(0,0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a few upvotes, so I am converting my comment to an answer. If you want to avoid reinstantiating over and over again inside the loop, your only way out is to create setter methods for your `ComplexNumber` class:

```
public void setReal(double real) { this.real = real; }
public void setImaginary(double im) { this.im = im; }
public void setTo(double real, double im) { setReal(real); setImaginary(im); }
```

I am assuming your class has fields called `real` and `im`.

Moreover, if you can't modify the class itself, you should extend it by creating a wrapper class of the form `class MyComplexNumber extends ComplexNumber`, and then implement the setter methods for MyComplexNumber.

Comment: I'm gonna try to implement those suggestions. It's my ComplexNumber class, so I can do whatever I want to it. BTW, I did what you recommended to define REAL numbers. See my "answer" below.

Answer (score 0):

Types are good but I don't see a need for them here if your problem is memory.

Try creating methods inside ComplexNumber such as

```
public void init(){
  //clear and reset all variables inside ComplexNumber
  ...
}
```

and

```
public void set(param1, param2...){
  //set required variables
  ...
}
```

Then use set() and init() respectively inside your loop instead of creating a new instance each time. This works if you don't need references to the objects created inside the loop.

Comment: No, no _NEED_ for types, but, having already made the ComplexNumber class (and a lame-to-decent complex number calculator out of it), I felt like, of all places (Mandelbrot set), this would be a very good place to apply the class again. It does clarify the textbook's code, somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I should have pointed out in advance that the following code--with no `new`, no setters--accomplishes the task:

```
    z1.real = x * dx - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetX;
    z1.imag = y * dy - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetY;
    z0.real = 0;
    z0.imag = 0;
```

I was just hoping for something along the lines of my original revised code, one line per complex number.

====================

Here's me extending `ComplexNumber` class into a `RealNumber` class (which seems a bit backward, but...):

```
class RealNumber extends ComplexNumber 
{  // RealNumber IS-A subclass ...

  RealNumber() {}

  RealNumber(double r) {
    super.imag = 0;                         // ... THIS kind of subclass ... 
    super.real = r;                         // ... of ComplexNumber!           
  }
}
```

============================

Hey, @Chthonic, this worked:

```
public void setReal(double real) { this.real = real; }
public void setImaginary(double imag) { this.imag = imag; }
public void makeComplex(double real, double imag) { setReal(real); setImaginary(imag); }
```

...

```
    z1 = new ComplexNumber();
    z0 = new ComplexNumber(); // before loop
```

...

```
    z1.makeComplex(x * dx - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetX,y * dy - zoomFactor / 2 + offsetY);
    z0.makeComplex(0, 0);
```

THANKS for the idea. I'm not certain I got exactly why my original z1 = new Complex... didn't work, but I'll think about the replies.

(I just realized that I "learned" something that I already "knew". Happens all the time.)

Comment: Glad to know you got it working. Btw, setters and getters are needed only if the fields are not public. About the `new` issue: I suspect you simply removed the word `new` from the code. If that is so, then the compiler will treat it as a method, not instantiation.